# Round decimal place only to 3 places

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need to round the decimal places only to three:

Here is my code:

```
var split_arr = subtotal_string.split(".", subtotal_string);
var integer = split_arr[0];
var decimal = split_arr[1];

var decimal_new = decimal.toFixed(3);
```

But this is not working..

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: what is subtotal_string ..?

Comment: What did you expect and what do you get instead? decimal_new is a String btw.

Comment: if have the subtotal_string as 93.4366346, i need the output as 93.436 or 93.437..is it possible to do this? i need to round the decimal part only

Comment: i think i got the answer  var subtotal_new = Math.round( subtotal_string * 1000 ) / 1000;

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split it, just cast the string as a number (`+`) then call `toFixed()`:

```
var threeDP = (+subtotal_string).toFixed(3);
// 9.43663436 -> 9.437
```

Comment: Actually how about if have the subtotal_string as 93.4366346? i need the value as 93.436 or 93.437..is it possible to do this?